# Can't access vm from other computers in the network

Tags: windows-7, nat, vmware-workstation

HOST OS: windows 7 64
Guest OS windows server 2008 32
Vmware Worstation 7.1
Network Connection Type: NAT

I can access my application from the guest os using the computer name or localhost but if I try to access it from another computer in the network it doesn't work.

I tried to do NAT port forwarding:

[image: vmware]

but it still doesn't work.

Typing: http://localhost:8080/myapp from the host machine doesn't work and typing the ip address or computer name from another computer doesn't work as well.

Using bridged is not really an option as it seems to break connectivity of some of my app modules.

Firewalls are off on both vm and host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the VMware Virtual Network Editor and setup one of the network connections to be Bridged and specify the network card they are going to use.

Then go into the VM's settings within VMware Workstation and change the network connection to use your new bridge 'VMnet0-9'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the virtual machine settings from NAT to the Bridged network mode.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. As stated in the question using bridged mode breaks connectivity of some modules that my web app uses. Is there anyway to access a vm from a different computer in NAT Mode?

Comment: +1 Use bridged networking and diagnose the web app issue instead.